# How can I set a breakpoint that triggers when a property is modified?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a public property with a read and write methods to a private field. I tried adding a data breakpoint for the field or property and I get an "Invalid address" error message. I qualified the variable name with the type name. Same Error.
I also tried to put a regular breakpoint on the write method and the line turns green.

How do I break when the value of a variable changed in Delphi XE?

**Update**

This is a sample code:

```
Type
 TCustromer

private
 customerName: string;
public 
  property CustomerName: string  read customerName   write customerName;
end;
```

How do I break whenever CustomerName or customerName values change?

Comment: Are you in build or release configuration? Do you have more than one project open in a project group? Is this unit a part of your project or outside of it?

Comment: Data break points work fine. I always set them by giving the absolute address.

Comment: @Jerry No to all. Regular breakpoints fire fine. Question here how to use  a variable for the address field?

Comment: You said "I also tried to put a regular breakpoint on the write method and the line turns green." which means it's not working fine.

Comment: In other words set the address as `$xxxxxxxx` where you use the actual hex address.

Comment: @David How do you get the absolute address for a variable? If I use Inspect I get "Error inspecting 'xxxx': expression error" message

Comment: @Jerry Breakpoints in code fire. Breakpoints where properties are defined are green.

Comment: I would imagine you could write `@ObjVar.FieldName` to get the address. The expression `@Typename.FieldName` wouldn't help because there's no such thing. Fields only have addresses when they're attached to object instances.

Comment: To set a breakpoint on a property setter, you need to put it in the setter's implementation, not in the property declaration. The property declaration doesn't represent any executable code, which is the only place a regular breakpoint can go.

Comment: @Rob Exactly what I was about to say. I was assuming OP put the breakpoint in implementation already.

Comment: @Rob I come from .NET world. Delphi is new to me. In Visual Studio I can put a breakpoint in a property setter in the property declaration and it fires whenever an instance of the type sets that property regardless where it's happening in code. There could be a hundred places where the property is set. It's impractical to put a breakpoint in each place. I am looking for something similar in Delphi. I assumed if I put a breakpoint on the write method, it fires whenever an instance of that type sets the property value.

Comment: @Tony I think you're still misunderstanding. "normal breakpoint" means it's in the implementation of that property setter, not the interface or any other place where that property might be set.. That would be inside the actual property setter procedure, i.e. `SetMyProperty(Value: String);`

Comment: Ahh, so you don't have a property setter procedure in this case. You can create a Getter and Setter method, for example `property CustomerName: String read GetCustomerName write SetCustomerName;` and then set your breakpoints inside those methods.

Comment: @Jerry I posted an update. I don't see any implementation. Whenever CustomerName changes, the write method changes customerName? Isn't that what happens?

Comment: Yes, my comment was based on seeing your update. The Read and Write methods can execute whatever code you wish (presumably getting/setting your variable). Rob's answer below covers exactly this. The only disadvantage to this approach is you can't catch whenever the variable itself is changed directly outside of the property.

Comment: @Jerry, I wouldn't call it a disadvantage because the purpose of properties is to *hide the fields*. You're not supposed to change them from *outside* (`strict private` visibility specifier would express that better).

Comment: @TLama Indeed but there are many cases when one may need to change the private field internally within the object. For example, many of my property setters have `Invalidate`, and sometimes I need to set those variables without calling `Invalidate`.

Comment: @Jerry, ah, I see. I would call it just *from inside* (the class implementation) rather than *from outside*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're coming from .Net, where the compilers replace direct-field property setters with stub methods. With that setup, I could understand why an IDE might let you put a breakpoint on the property declaration and interpret it as breakpoints in those hidden stub methods.

Delphi doesn't work that way, though. When a property declaration says it writes to a field, then assignments to the property assign *directly* to the field. There's no setter method to break in.

To detect writes to the property in your program, you *could* try to set data breakpoints. However, you'd have to do that for *every* instance of your class because each instance's field obviously lives at a different address. Furthermore, you'd have to do that anew *every* time you restarted your program because the instances' addresses wouldn't necessarily stay the same from one run to the next.

The easier way to accomplish your goal is simply to write a setter for your property. Then set a breakpoint in the implementation of that setter.

```
type
  TCustomer = class
  private
    FCustomerName: string;
    procedure SetCustomerName(const Value: string);
  public 
    property CustomerName: string read FCustomerName write SetCustomerName;
  end;

procedure TCustomer.SetCustomerName(const Value: string);
begin // Set breakpoint here.
  FCustomerName := Value;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but Delphi used to allow data breakpoints for this purpose. I don't know if XE has it but I'd guess that it does.

Comment: Yes, I see it now in the comments, guess I was expecting to see it in the more prominent answers section. I have not used XE yet, it's too expensive.